# Google Chart not showing info from google sheet unless sheet is accessed

Tags: google-visualization, google-sheets

I have a bunch of sheets that I'm using to store the marks of my students for a couple of my classes. On my website, I am using HTML and Google's Query Language to pull info from the sheets (2 columns...the students numbers of each student and their mark). If I've edited the spreadsheet on any given day, the chart shows up properly, but if I have not edited it that day then it shows incorrect values for their marks or old values for their marks. I think it's something to do with the sheets, but I can't be sure.

Here's the HTML code from my site:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", '1', {packages:['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
  var query = new google.visualization.Query(
      'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=14mPTcYYraMyuBnEFSJW74ZQ3xjWSSOuDqoxB2VrvAvw&tq=select%20D%2C%20E%20where%20D%3C%3E%22Avatar%22%20order%20by%20E%20desc%20label%20E%20%22Experience%20Points%22');

  query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
  if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }

  var data = response.getDataTable();
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('columnchart'));

var options = {'title':'Experience Points',
                     'width':'927',
                     'height':'510',
'chartArea': {'left':'50', 'width':'90%'},
legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 2 },
hAxis: {showTextEvery: 1, slantedText: true, slantedTextAngle: 90, viewWindow:{max:33}},
bar:{groupWidth: '60%'},
isStacked: true};

chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>

<title>Data from a Spreadsheet</title>
</head>

<body>
<span id='columnchart'></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas? By the way, the sheet is set so that anyone on the internet can find and view.

Comment: Similar problem here: I have a Google Sheet that provides the data by a range of columns for a Google Chart inside an HTML page.  The columns in the Sheet are calculated from other columns.  When some hours have passed since the Google Chart has accessed the Google Sheet, the chart complains about the format of the Sheet.  And when I then manually access the Sheet through Google Drive, the Chart works fine.

Comment: (cont.) The exact error message from Charts is "All series on a given axis must be of the same data type".